# jQuery DatetimePicker Plugin - onClose event does not fire on IE Webview (PhoneGap) Application

Tags: jquery, cordova, datetimepicker

I am developing PhoneGap Application which will run on windows IE webview. In the application we are using DatetimePicker plugin mentioned below:
jQuery DateTimePicker Plugin (http://umcdatetimepicker.codeplex.com)

This plugin perfectly work on all Mac however its has strange behavior on Windows webview as its onClose function does work as expected.

We are showing Calendar on click of calendar image. Calendar get close if i click anywhere on screen. However it just get hide and non of event get fire on close of the calendar. I have put alert for testing which does fire with other logic. I have written my own onSelect and onClose event which overwrite main plugin action.

As i mentioned above calendar just hide but event does not get call. After hiding calendar if i click on calendar then only it fire onClose event and throw me alert used for testing purpose. It mean i can only fire onClose event correctly on Calendar image. Both event work perfectly on IE7/8 browser but onClose event does not work on IE Webview. I have tried multiple things but didn't work. Here is my code

```
$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
            onSelect:function($this){
                //alert($this);
               alert("i am selected");
            $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;
            var hour = $('.ui-datepicker .dateimepicker-hour').val();
            //alert (hour);
                var minuts = $('.ui-datepicker .dateimepicker-minuts').val();
                //alert (minuts);
                var second = $('.ui-datepicker .dateimepicker-second').val();//alert (second);

                var time = hour + ":" + minuts + ":" + second;
                //alert (time);
                //alert($this +" "+ time);
            $("#datetimepicker").attr("value",$this +" "+ time);
            },
            onClose: function() {
                alert("its on close");
                var currentsetdate = $(this).val();
                if(currentsetdate == ""){}
                else{
                //alert (currentsetdate);
                var onlydate = currentsetdate.split(' ')[0];
                //alert (onlydate);
             $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
             var hour = $('.ui-datepicker .dateimepicker-hour').val();
            //alert (hour);
                var minuts = $('.ui-datepicker .dateimepicker-minuts').val();
                //alert (minuts);
                var second = $('.ui-datepicker .dateimepicker-second').val();//alert (second);

                var time = hour + ":" + minuts + ":" + second;
                //alert (time);
                 $("#datetimepicker").attr("value",onlydate +" "+ time);
                }}
```

Does any one one have idea about limitation code. It would be good if any one help out get the solution. Is it possible to bind onClose event of calendar any where on body?

Regards,
Jitendra